# dropdownlist no function, error creating control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a gridview and a drop list, one with function, the other that has no function, so just a tag. Can't seem to resolve this, even though I have `runat=server` in my tag.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding as mentioned by others, but it doesn't work for me, the error is still showing.

> Error Creating Control - asp:dropdownlist id="dropdownlist1" runat="server"The end tag is missing for .
>
> Error Creating Control - asp:gridview id="gridview1" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="false" No 'runat=server' attribute present on the gridview id="gridview1" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="false"  tag.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList> 
            <br />



           <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                CellPadding="6" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"    
   
OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
```

Comment: show your more of your code

Answer (score 0):

You have two

`runat="server"`

Remove 1 of it

I think your problem occurs because you rename the page i guess.

You have to use the new name of your page and inherit it into the working page

like:

```
Inherits="YournewPagename"
```

Comment: didn't rename the pages with errors , but the inherits are the correct.
`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>`

`public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page`

Removing the runat=server on the first tag, gives me no `runat="server"` attribute present

Comment: try to create a new project if the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList> 
            <br />



           <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                CellPadding="6" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"    

OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"> 
               </asp:GridView>
```